# Split Integer and Insert Symbol in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `erb` template in Rails and I want to split integer in half and put symbol between them.

`@user.number = 99999999999`

I would like to display it like this: `999999 - 99999`. How could I display `-` after sixth character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @number = @user.number.to_s %>
<%= @number[0..5] %> - <℅= @number[6..10] %>
```

Comment: Your code worked perfectly. Thanks. don't know why, but i had to re-wright every `<%` and `%>` in your code.

Comment: I typed this on my phone. Anyway I updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the purpose of putting `-` sign **exactly** after sixth digit, but in case you're simply looking for some human-readable representation of a large number, you could use Rails [number helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html). There are various methods there, just to mention a few:

```
number_to_human(1234567890123456)
# => "1.23 Quadrillion"
number_with_delimiter(12345678, delimiter: ",")
# => 12,345,678
```

Comment: i want to put `-` because it is format for social security number. There has to be `-` symbol

Comment: does it have exactly 11 digits in all cases? is that a standard representation to have them separated after the 6th one?

Comment: It depends in which country you are!

Comment: in this case you've got to have some kind of options array, each option representing a single country SSN format. this can not be achieved by simply delimiting any given SSN after the 6th sign.

Comment: i just needed to insert `-` after sixth character! i know it is absolutely needed for my project. Thanks for help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a method in your model, or in an helper too.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def number_to_ssn
  number.to_s.scan(/{.1,6}/}.join(' - ')
 end
end


module UsersHelper
 def ssn_for(user)
  user.number.to_s.scan(/{.1,6}/).join(' - ')
 end
end
```

And call it in your view:

```
<%= @user.number_to_ssn %>

<%= ssn_for(@user) %>
```